# OpenGL: Create a "transparent window-like object"

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, vuforia

I am developing an augmented reality app, that should render a 3D model. So far so good. I am using Vuforia for AR, libgdx for graphics, everything is on Android, works like charm...

Problem is, that I need to create a "window - like" effect. I literally need to make the model look like a window you can look through and see behind it. That means I have some kind of wall-object, which has a hole in it(a window). Through this hole, you can see another 3D model behind the wall.

[image: Side View]
[image: User View]

Problem is, I need to also render the video background. And this background is also behind the wall. I can't just turn of blending when rendering the wall, because that would corrupt the video image.

So I need to make the wall and everything directly behind it transparent, but not the video background.

Is such marvel even possible using only OpenGL?

I have been thinking about some combination of front-to-end and back-to-front rendering: render background first, then render the wall, but blend it only into the alpha channel (making video visible only on pixels that are not covered by wall), then render the actual content, but blend it only into the visible pixels (that are not behind the wall) and then "render" the wall once more, but this time make everything behind it visible. Would such thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't just turn of blending when rendering the wall

What makes you think that? OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a drawing API and everything happens in the order and as you call it.

So order of operations would be

1. Draw video background with blending turned off.
2. The the objects between video and the wall (turn blending on or off as needed)
3. Draw the wall, with blending or alpha test enabled, so that you can create the window.

> Is such marvel even possible using only OpenGL?

The key in understanding OpenGL is, that you don't think of using it to setup a 3D world scene, but instead use it to draw a 2D picture of a 3D world (because that's what OpenGL actually does). In the end OpenGL is just a bit smarter brush to draw onto a flat canvas. Think about how you'd paint a picture on paper, how you'd mask different parts. And then you do *that* with OpenGL.

#### Update

Ohkay, now I see what you want to achieve. The wall is not really visible, but a depth dependent mask. Easy enough to achieve: Use *alpha testing* instead of blending to produce the window in the depth buffer. Or, instead of alpha testing you could just draw 4 quads, which form a window between them.

The trick is, that you draw it into just the depth buffer, but not into the color buffer.

```
glDepthMask(1);
glColorMask(0,0,0,0);
draw_wall();
```

Blending will not work in this case, since even fully transparent fragments will end up in the depth buffer. Hence alpha test. In fixed function OpenGL `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)` and `glAlphaFunc(…)`. However on OpenGL-ES2 you've to implement it through a shader.

Say you've got a single channel texture, in the fragment shader do

```
float opacity = texture(sampler, uv).r;
if( opacity < threshold ) discard;
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand, or, maybe I didn't specify it correctly - I need the wall transparent too, and the content behind it. From the users point of view, the video background should be the "wall". Just to be clear, you are suggesting that I draw the background. Then, I draw the objects, with classic src_alpha,1-src_aplha blending. They are drawn over the background. Then I draw the wall. But how should I set up the blending/aplha tests to make the wall and rendered content behind transparent, but not the video? When I redraw the video with objects, the video pixels are gone, no?

Comment: @daemontus: Could you please sketch it up in Photoshop? I just want to see what you want it to look like.

Comment: Ok, I am a lousy sketcher in PS, so I used paper instead, but I hope you get the idea :) From Users point of view: https://www.dropbox.com/s/96ubs36qin3o4mh/IMG_20140410_105513613.jpg
And how I imagine a scene could look like from "above": https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bhkb3pxhql0hji/IMG_20140410_105521256.jpg

Comment: Of course, if you have a better idea how to achieve the effect from picture one, I'd love to hear it. It just occurred to me, that another "invsible wall" would do the trick if I render it with good shaders/blending.

Comment: Great, thank you very much :) Just to make sure, if I understand: First I render the wall, but the color and depth mask ensure, that only the depth buffer is modified. Then, I render the content, without colorMask, so the values in depth buffer prevent the content behind the wall from rendering. But why the alphaTest?

Comment: @daemontus: The alpha test is to create the window (in case you're using a texture to cut out the window). If your wall consists of 4 quads, forming the window, then you don't need the alpha test at all.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Actually, I have the "window" from the 3D artist as model with actual hole, so no need for alpha test. I just tried to implement it and it works marvelously, so thank you for all help.